# how i add new full contact to WP with C# code?

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I want to add new contact to WP's contact list with C# code. but not with SaveContactTask or SavePhoneNumberTask or etc.

I want to add advanced contact to WP contact database. How can I get access to Contact Database of Windows Phone to save my contact data ?

Comment: why woudn't you watn to use the SaveContactTask?

Comment: i have many phone types as home, work, fax, etc, but SaveContactTask hasnt these all or there are other facts.
I want to create my own advanced MyContact class like Contacts class of WP and save it WP contact database. To my mind, it may be possible, but i cannot find ;(

Comment: @JeffV : is there any way to get `SaveContactTask` from a `Contact` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way this is possible is through the [`SaveContactTask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.savecontacttask%28v=VS.92%29.aspx). Windows Phone limits applications access to many of the functions of the underlying OS's data.

Comment: I save my contact with SaveContactTask, then i see new added contact in listbox. But, i restart application, new added contact disappears.
Why does SaveContactTask not save contact??? please, help